# Do we need a Canadian visa for our cruise from Seattle to Alaska?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, canada, cruising, alaska

We are Indian passport holders and have US multiple entry visa. We have booked an Alaska cruise which departs and returns to Seattle, Washington. Do we need Canadian visa, too, to embark on the cruise?

Comment: Will the cruiseship stop in a Canadian port? If yes, are you planning to go off the ship in that port?

Comment: @Neusser if there is a port of call in Canada, you aren't able to board at all without requisite visas, even if you don't intend to disembark.

Answer (score 4):

If your cruise itinerary has a Canadian port of call, as many do between Seattle and Alaska, you would need a [Canadian visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp). You would want to visit the web site of company through which you've booked your cruise. Look for travel documentation; passengers are expected to obtain any needed visas in advance. Without them, you not only wouldn't be allowed to board, most explicitly mention that there are no refunds or replacement cruises.